# Default DataGrid RowStyle partially used when alternative is explicitly specified

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Please see the below demonstration of my problem.

```
<Border xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Border.Resources>
        <!--  Default style -->
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding UnrelatedProperty}" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="SpecificStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
        </Style>
    </Border.Resources>
    <DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource SpecificStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column" Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <system:String>Dummy Item 1</system:String>
        <system:String>Dummy Item 2</system:String>
        <system:String>Dummy Item 3</system:String>
        <system:String>Dummy Item 4</system:String>
    </DataGrid>
</Border>
```

The rows show in blue as desired, but I also get the following binding errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnrelatedProperty' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-121747943)'. BindingExpression:Path=UnrelatedProperty; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-121747943); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnrelatedProperty' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=1834567193)'. BindingExpression:Path=UnrelatedProperty; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1834567193); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnrelatedProperty' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-504084967)'. BindingExpression:Path=UnrelatedProperty; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-504084967); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnrelatedProperty' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-1313389031)'. BindingExpression:Path=UnrelatedProperty; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-1313389031); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

The binding to UnrelatedProperty is required for other grids which work fine.  However in this grid, the style shouldn't be in use at all.  It looks like the default style is also getting partially applied although SpecificStyle does not specify BasedOn, and the text is not red.

My question is: what is this happening here?  I can solve the problem by giving the default style `x:Key="DefaultRowStyle"` and apply using the following style – but I'm more interested in understanding the source of the problem.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}" />
</Style>
```

**Edit:**

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: each `DataGridRow` has implicit DataContext as the data item (which is a `string` as in your code). So your Style set the `Visibility` of each row based on `{Binding UnrelatedProperty}`, that property is not found on each `string`, of course.

Comment: @Hopeless That makes sense. But why is the style with the `{Binding UnrelatedProperty}` being used at all?

Comment: that Style is applied by default because you don't use explicit `x:Key`, which is then set to `{x:Type DataGridRow}` internally (when added to a ResourceDictionary which always requires a key from the added element).

Comment: @Hopeless But the `DataGrid` specifies another Style `RowStyle="{StaticResource SpecificStyle}"`.  If the default style was applied, why isn't the text colour red?

Comment: maybe it merges the Style, the explicit Style (blue) overrides the implicit style (red), while the `Visibility` property has no override, so it still applies.

Comment: @Hopeless I made the foreground red and the background blue to help show that this wasn't happening in the way you might expect.  I've also researched style merging which people usually write custom classes and things to do – so that is not straight forward.  The style doesn't inherit because I haven't used BasedOn.

Comment: Your problem seems quite interesting but looks like it's just a problem of validating the code, it's quite useful to notify any error in XAML. Finally  the implicit style cannot be applied. Answering to your problem means answering another question: ***Is the implicit Style actually applied first (and then be overridden by the explicit Style) or just validated for error reporting purpose?*** I'm not sure about that, it's hard to know what  actually it does. But as I said finally the explicit Style will be applied, we don't need to care much about the issue here (even some performance issue).

Comment: @Hopeless, yes I wondered something similar to your overriding suggestion.  I know it's not showstopping, and I have a workaround.  However I like to clear all binding errors so I don't miss good ones in the noise.  Also, it feels like a WPF bug to me which is why I posted the question.

Comment: if your Bindings (in the implicit Style) are correct, no errors will be reported. I don't think we need some big workaround here. Just try to make everything correct. (in your example you created a situation in which some binding error should be surely present to test it).

Comment: @Hopeless The workaround is simple, I included it in the question.  I kept the above sample simple so others could reproduce the problem.  In my production application, `UnrelatedProperty` is provided by a base class that all the other grids (50+) use and work correctly without error.  There are two that use types from another hierarchy, and these show binding errors.